# what's the difference between child state and sticky state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I have a good use of angular 1.5 states (nested states, tab states, modal stats)

Ui-router-extras has *sticky states*, but I dont see the difference with a classic parent/child state architecture ?

The basic example of sticky state is something we can do without sticky ?
http://plnkr.co/edit/SCHExh4DYKFd9Kq3UbaA?p=preview

If you remove the `sticky: true`, you get the same behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really. What `ui-router` does is actually that it transforms your app into a state machine. And a strict definition of a state machine is that **you can only have one state active at any point of time**.

Now what that means is whenever you transit from `stateA` to `stateB`, `stateA`'s scope (and other assets like controllers etc) will be destroyed, while `stateB` ones being instantiated. So literally, you cannot have `stateA`'s and `stateB`'s controller and scope being active simultaneously. Conclusion is, no parallel (aka sticky) states are allowed in a strict state machine.

`ui-router-extras` let's you do this. You can have multiple states active at a time.

Let's have an example scenario.

1. You first go to `stateA`.
2. In `stateA`, you started to countdown from 100 seconds to 0.
3. Halfway through 57th second, you go to `stateB` to retrieve some data. You spend 10 seconds at `stateB`.
4. You go back to `stateA`

Now, for a normal `ui-router`. When you are at step4 going back to `stateA`, your countdown restarts from 100 seconds. Where as with sticky states, your coundown starts from 57-10 = 47 seconds.

This is important because for the normal `ui-router`, when you transit to `stateB`, your `stateA`'s scope is destroyed. Transiting back to `stateA` will re-instantiate everything, hence countdown start from 100 again. If you are using sticky states, the scopes are preserved.

Here is [plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gAv8ZBaDiw19IRiUtwbI?p=preview) forked from yours. Try comment out the `sticky:true`, and go and forth from tab1 and tab 2, and you will see the difference.